# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix $A - sI$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a $3*3$ matrix with eigenvalues $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$ and corresponding eigenvectors $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$. Let $s$ be a given number. Suppose that $a_1$ is the eigenvalue nearest to $s$ and $a_2$ is the eigenvalue furthest from $s$, and let $I$ denote the $3*3$ identity matrix.

i) What are the eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenvectors of the matrix $A - sI$?

ii) What is the dominant eigenvalue of the matrix $A - sI$?

iii)What is the eigenvalue of the matrix $A - sI$ with the smallest absolute value?

Because this is more of a theoretical than a practical question, I have difficulty making sense of it. I know how to work out the dominant eigenvalue and the smallest eigenvalue using the power method on an actual matrix with entries, but it seems this question wants the answer in mathematical notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$(A-sI)x_1 = Ax_1 - sIx_1 = a_1 x_1 - sx_1 = (a_1-s)x_1$$

Comment: Does $a_1$ in your hint represent an entry in the $A$ matrix or the eigenvalue $a_1$?

Comment: If $a_1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $(a_1 - s)$ is an eigenvalue of $A - sI$. Am I right?

Comment: The eigenvalue, of course.  After all, that is how we were allowed to make that simplification

Comment: And $(a_1 - s)x_1$ the corresponding eigenvector?

Comment: Sure... so long as it isn't zero, but more importantly x1 is

Comment: How would $a_1$'s nearness to $s$ relate to the size of the eigenvalues as hinted to in the problem statement?

Comment: You said "more importantly $x_1$" is. Isn't $x_1$ the eigenvector of A and not of the matrix $A - sI$?

Comment: It is an eigenvector for *both*. Reread your definitions. As for the nearness of a1 to s versus the nearness of a3 to s, think about it a bit more.  What is the full list of eigenvalues for A-sI?

Comment: Full list of eigenvalues for $A-sI$ are $a_1 - s$, $a_2 -s$ and $a_3 -s$. Since $a_1$ is closest to $s$, $a_1 - s$ will be the smallest eigenvalue?

Comment: Precisely.  That is after all exactly what is meant by "a1 is closest to s"

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate.